# Subjunctive - könnte or kann?

Tags: grammaticality, subjunctive, grammatical-mood

Which is correct?

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben **könnte**.
>
> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben **kann**.

Should I use *Konjuktiv 2* for *können*?

Comment: None of both either you say "hätte es" or you say "hätte das" both (as you posted) is wrong.

Comment: Yes, Thank you but except from that should i use konjuctiv 2 for Konnen?

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Thank you sir.

Comment: Inhaltlich stimme ich nicht zu, aber darum geht es ja nicht. Was soll denn ausgedrückt werden? Vielleicht: "Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bliebe"? Die Erwartung, dass letzteres die Konsequenz des Ersteren wäre?

Comment: A better sentence (content wise) would be: Wenn man sich vegan ernähren würde, hätte es denn Vorteil, dass man im Schnitt gesünder bleibt.

Comment: @infinitezero: I would propose to change your proposal to `Wenn man sich vegan ernähren würde, hätte es den Vorteil, dass man im Schnitt gesünder _bliebe`. hätte-hätte-fahrradkette bis zum Ende :-o

Answer (score 4):

All options are grammatically correct.

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben könnte.

This kind of implies that there is only a chance to stay healthy if you ate vegan, otherwise you would get sick. It would translate to

> If one would eat vegan it would have the advantage one **might** remain healthy

The meaning in

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben kann.

goes more into the direction that vegan food would increase the chance to remain healthy.

But in a context like this I would expect

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben würde.

which means that eating vegan has the result that one remains healthy.

Comment: ... oder auch nicht. ;)

Comment: @scienceponder Das ist jetzt kein so nützlicher Kommentar. Wäre gut, wenn Du zumindest einen Punkt aufgreifst, den Du für zweifelhaft hältst..

Comment: Mein Kommentar erhebt gar nicht den Anspruch, nützlich zu sein. Auch bei Stackexchange muss mal ein kleiner Scherz erlaubt sein. Die auf ein Fortsetzung hinweisenden Punkte zu Beginn meines Kommentars, machen eigentlich deutlich, wie er gemeint ist. "Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben kann/würde oder auch nicht."

Answer (score 2):

Two correct options:

1. Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben könnte.
2. Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben kann.

Leftout option: "hätte es den Vorteil"

Difference:

1. It is not causal determined if you stay healthy due to vegan food. Might be, some correlations imply it.
2. It is almost causal determined that you stay healthy due to vegan food - regarding your nutritions. And leaving open the rest of your lifestyle.

So *Konjunktiv II* / *könnte* leaves room if the nutrition aspect is causally linked with vegan food while *kann* the causal link implies. There is still a probability left, just a small one (regarding nutrition).

3. Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleibt.

That *bleibt* would clear all questions regarding healthy nutrition - this way anything else than vegan food undermines your health. It also implies that vegan nutrition would play a major role in staying healthy.

Comment: Wow!!! Vielen Dank für Ihre ausführliche Antwort.

Comment: Another question just occurred to me:can we say  Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund bleiben würde

Comment: @AmirShahnazar: thinking longer about it, it could be grammatically correct to use only `kann` as I remember some people say `könnte` is "artificial".  I just stand with the meaning that `gesund bleiben kann` implies causal linking. Your `gesund bleiben würde` has the same implication as `kann`: you strongly imply that this is a fact.

Comment: Thank you again

Comment: @ShegitBrahm To me, also 1. and 2. mean (or at least heavily imply) that eating vegan is the only option if you want to stay healthy.

Answer (score 2):

Both sentences seem hyper-constructions to me, both are rather awkward and most of all, unidiomatic. They sound like someone tried to throw as many words as possible into them.

If someone thinks that the idea should be expressed the way it was, the proposal of *user unknown* is the most adequate:

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund
>   bliebe.

But *bliebe* is quite stilted, therefore the following would be more likely:

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, hätte das den Vorteil, dass man gesund
>   bleiben würde.

And yet, even these are not really pragmatic. I'd suggest to keep one's feet on the ground and say:

> Wenn man vegan essen würde, wäre das vielleicht besser / günstiger für
>   die Gesundheit.

Or even more unpretentiously:

> Vegane Ernährung wäre vielleicht besser / günstiger für die
>   Gesundheit.

The latter *hat den Vorteil* that is does not contain a presupposition. But that is a seperate question. ;-)